# How to get the URL query params in Pedestal?

Tags: clojure, pedestal

How do I get the URL params into the request map in Pedestal? I am assuming that this needs the use of an interceptor? However the Pedestal documentation (or severe lack thereof) does not make this at all clear. Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Query parameters [are parsed automatically](https://github.com/pedestal/pedestal/blob/master/guides/documentation/service-routing.md#query-parameters) by Pedestal, and the resulting map is placed in the request map under the `:query-params` key.

As a simple example, start with the pedestal-service template and use the following definitions:

```
(defn home-page
  [request]
  (ring-resp/response (format "Hello with params: %s" (:query-params request))))

(defroutes routes
  [[["/" {:get home-page}]]])
```

Now if you browse to `http://localhost:8080/?param=true&other=1234`, you should see `Hello world with paramters: {:param "true", :other "1234"}`.

Comment: Thanks. In the link you provide it talks about "the context" (as in: When a request matches this route, the whole vector of interceptors gets pushed onto the context.) I am confused, does it mean the request map when it talks about the 'context'?

Comment: Not exactly. The [context](https://github.com/pedestal/pedestal/blob/master/guides/documentation/service-context-reference.md) is something that gets passed around the interceptor chain, and it contains the request map among other items.